# Virtualbox Windows 7 guest, Ubuntu host, no internet connection -- working prior to upgrade

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

I tried to install the new Virtualbox 5.0 (upgrading from 4.3.10) on Ubuntu 14.04.  I have successfully run Virtualbox (4.3.10 and earlier versions) for years on Ubuntu 14.04 (and earlier), but I could get no connection with Virtualbox 5.0.  I read threads for 6 hours and tried NAT and Bridged and everything imaginable.

One other variable:  I had just copied my VM vdi to my new Seagate Expansion 5TB USB external drive and I was at first trying to run from there.

But now:  even after completely removing VB 5.0 and reinstalling VirtualBox 4.3.10, and going back to a vdi on one of my regular SATA drives, I can get no internet connection in my Win7 guest.  I cannot ping any IP at all.

In the Win7 Device Manager, under Network Adapters, I have 4 items, all starting out with yellow exclamation points:
Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter   (this is also set in the vb settings)
WAN Miniport (IP)
WAN Miniport (IPv6)
WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)

When I uninstall the Intel Desktop Adapter, then reinstall it, the yellow exclamation point goes away, as if its working properly, but there is no change in my non-working internet connection.

Here is ifconfig from my Ubuntu host (note:  some entries are from a previously unfinished VPN setup but they never caused any problems with my VM and nothing else has changed besides what I've mentioned):

```
ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:6d:04:25:67:7f  
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f66d:4ff:fe25:677f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1383682 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:988203 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1148303939 (1.1 GB)  TX bytes:240381867 (240.3 MB)
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:568 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:568 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:69229 (69.2 KB)  TX bytes:69229 (69.2 KB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.9.0.1  P-t-P:10.9.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

tun1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.1  P-t-P:10.8.0.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2e:2a:79:b5:5c:15  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

And here's the ipconfig from the Windows 7 guest:

Here too is the result of ipconfig from the win7 guest:  `

```
:\Users\Chris>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Chris-Win7-Ult
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.monkeybrains.net:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

C:\Users\Chris>
```

Lastly, shouldn't be an issue but I am running everything behind the D-link Dir-601 router and have been for many years.

Comment: Here too is the result of ipconfig from the win7 guest:

Answer (score 1):

ipconfig shows that there are no any network adapters visible to Windows guest. AFAIK, VirtualBox generate a new MAC for every new network adapter, so, maybe, MAC for your "Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter" was regenerated. Windows expects NIC with old MAC address. Easy way to solve a problem: delete "Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter" from VM config and add a new one, but another model. Should help.

Answer (score -1):

apt-get purge-ing everything and completely reinstalling  VB 4.3.10 again seems to have solved the problem.  Sorry, I have no explanation.